# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) using Redcarpet Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcarpet

I'm trying to use the `Redcarpet` gem to render markdown on my app and am getting the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` on my erb page where I call the render:

```
<p><%= markdown.render(@wiki.body) %></p>
```

Here's my `application_helper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def markdown(text)
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true, tables: true)
  end
end
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  I've read a bunch of SO posts on this, but I'm new to this gem.

Comment: What is your stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper should look more like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def markdown(text)
    md = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true, tables: true)
    md.render(text)
  end
end
```

and called like so:

```
<p><%= markdown(@wiki.body) %></p>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you for the fix!